Integration of Gaussian functions takes ages
I am trying essentially to compute a fourier transform with Integrate.
1]Is integrate faster or slower than FourierTransform?
2]Does anyone know how to efficiently calculate these integrals?
My code is the following
$Assumptions = {h > 0, d > 0, p0 >= 0, s > 0, M > 0, 
  L2 \[Element] Reals, dt \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals, 
  y \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals, p \[Element] Reals, 
  Dxx >= 0, Dpp >= 0}

h = 1
d = 100
s = 3
M = 1
p0 = 0
L2

xGpiu[x_] := xGpiu[x] = 
  Exp[-(x - d/2)^2/(2 s^2) + (I*(-p0)*(x - d/2))/(h)]/(Pi^(1/4)*Sqrt[s])

xGpiuconj[x_] :=  xGpiuconj[x] = 
  Exp[-(x - d/2)^2/(2 s^2) - (I*(-p0)*(x - d/2))/(h)]/(Pi^(1/4)*Sqrt[s])

pGpiu[p_] :=  pGpiu[p] = 
  Integrate[ xGpiu[x]*Exp[-I*p*x/h]/Sqrt[2*Pi*h], {x, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]

pGpiu[p]

pGpiuconj[p_] := Integrate[xGpiuconj[x]*Exp[+I*p*x/h]/Sqrt[2*Pi*h], {x, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
pGpiuconj[p]

XZUtGpiu[x_, z_, Dt_] := XZUtGpiu[x, z, Dt] = 
  Integrate[
   pGpiu[p]*Exp[-I*p^2*Dt/(2*M*h)]*
    Exp[I*p*(x - z)/h]/(Sqrt[2*Pi*h]), {p, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]

XZUtGpiu[x, z, dt]

GpiuUtdagYZ[y_, z_, Dt_] := GpiuUtdagYZ[y, z, Dt] = 
  Integrate[
   pGpiuconj[p]*Exp[+I*p^2*Dt/(2*M*h)]*
    Exp[-I*p*(y - z)/h]/(Sqrt[
       2*Pi*h]), {p, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]

GpiuUtdagYZ[y, z, dt]

XDecPiupiutY[x_, y_, Dt_] := XDecPiupiutY[x, y, Dt] = 
  Integrate[
   Exp[I/h*Dpp*Dt^2/M*z*(x - y)/L2]*Exp[-z^2/(2*L2)]*
    XZUtGpiu[x, z, Dt]*
    GpiuUtdagYZ[y, z, Dt], {z, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]

XDecPiupiutY[x, y, dt]

The first integrals are computed within seconds, while the last one, XDecPiupiutY[x, y, dt], does not come out with an output in hours.
Thank you in advance to anybody who will respond.

I am not sure this is the reason, but Dt is a reserved symbol in Mathematica. It stands for total derivative, so maybe change the variable.

Evaluation of the indefinite integral shows there is no problems with Dt, a function name,  in a Pattern

Evaluating the integrand Exp[I/h*Dpp*Dt^2/M*z*(x - y)/L2]*Exp[-z^2/(2*L2)]*     XZUtGpiu[x, z, Dt]*     GpiuUtdagYZ[y, z, Dt] of the last integral, Mathematica 12.2 shows a condition -9 < Im[Dt] < 9 . What is the parameter range of Dt to be condidered?

Adding GenerateConditions -> False takes 12 seconds on a fresh kernel in V14.1 (Mac M1):
ClearAll[XDecPiupiutY];
XDecPiupiutY[x_, y_, Dt_] := 
 XDecPiupiutY[x, y, Dt] = 
  Integrate[
   Exp[I/h*Dpp*Dt^2/M*z*(x - y)/L2]*Exp[-z^2/(2*L2)]*
     XZUtGpiu[x, z, Dt]*GpiuUtdagYZ[y, z, Dt] // 
    Echo, {z, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> False]

Assuming[{h > 0, d > 0, p0 >= 0, s > 0, M > 0, L2 \[Element] Reals, 
  dt \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals, 
  z \[Element] Reals, p \[Element] Reals, Dxx >= 0, Dpp >= 0},
 XDecPiupiutY[x, y, dt]
 ]

(*
1/Sqrt[(81 + dt^2 + 
 18 L2)/L2]3 Sqrt[2] E^-1/(
  2 L2 (81 + dt^2 + 18 L2))(Dpp^2 dt^4 (81 + dt^2) (x - y)^2 + 
    L2^2 (x - y)^2 + 
    L2 (45000 - (9 I + dt) (I + 2 Dpp dt^2) x^2 - 
       100 I (-9 I + dt + 18 Dpp dt^2) y - (-9 I + dt) (-I + 
          2 Dpp dt^2) y^2 + 
       4 x (-225 + 25 I dt + 450 I Dpp dt^2 + Dpp dt^3 y)))
*)

Of course, you lose some checking by Mathematica, but maybe the result could be checked by hand (or other computations).

You ran into the mess that Mathematica has with its definite integral input check. They try a list of known algorithms, primarily in the real line residues.,
The alternative of doing the indefinite integral, evaluating the difference at the boundaries, seems to be so obvious  to a mathematician, that he forgets that users from applied sciences often lack the basics.
If the result contains roots, use an assumption, that all symbols are PositiveReals.
I use
    PositiveIntegrate[expr_, range_,opt___] := 
      Integrate[expr, range, opt,
        Assumptions -> (# > 0 &) /@ 
            Union[Cases[{expr, range}, _Symbol, \[Infinity]]]] 

   Timing[XZUtGpiu[x, z, dt]] 

$$\left\{3.45313, \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\pi } \sqrt{s+\frac{i \text{dt} h}{M s}}}\exp \left(\frac{i \left(d^2 h M+4 d M \left(h (z-x)-i \text{p0} s^2\right)+4 i \text{dt} \text{p0}^2 s^2+4 M (x-z) \left(h x-h z+2 i \text{p0} s^2\right)\right)}{8 h \left(\text{dt} h-i M s^2\right)}\right)\right\}  $$
Evaluating the indefinite integral and taking the difference at the infinities works even faster, but again has indefinite erf functions at the infinities with coefficients of complicated function of the free coefficients.
Mathematicas course is to Reduce the value expression - mostly by its residues - by the construction of a logical decision tree. In all cases with more that 4 free parameters the desired complete solution  may not be  representable on a normal computer in finite memory in finite time.
Sometimes   even a worked out result challanges the rendering process on a machine. Work araound: calculate complex results without screen output by teminating ";" and inspect the result by Parts:  res[[0]] = Header,  res[[1,0]] =  Header of first argument.

Thank you. Do i need to specify the assumptions in Integrate[] even if I already stated them at the beginning?

There was always a conflict of  strategies with Assuming, $Assumptions and Assumptions->.
Reduce e.g.  neclects Assumptions under the assumption to act locally with a complete set of relations in its argument. One should spent an afternoon with execises for Integrate, Solve, Reduce etc

Seeing this, I have to wonder what is meant by "primarily in the real line residues".
